# How to make apk file using ionic framework with angular

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I have created simple apps in local directory, that app name is Ionic-Chat-master

How can i make this to apk file?

i have tried the following command using git but not worked for me

```
npm install -g cordova

cordova build --release android
```

This displays an error (`sh.exe": cordova: command not found`).

Comment: what os do you use? soonds like you have not add node mudule directory to your path.

Comment: You have to create sign-apk or regular apk?

Comment: i have just created an simple app in local environment.. i want to make it this file to apk file i have installed nodejs.. when i tried this "cordova build --release android" i got error..

Comment: I have used window 8.. i have installed nodejs..

Answer (score 28):

If you want generate .apk using Ionic FrameWork . thats very simple for the sake of this discussion I created the sample app and convert that sample app in to .apk using **Ionic Command**.

***1.Create*** a Ionic Sample App,

```
$ionic start Ionic-Chat-master
```

***2.Adding a platform*** to that project

for ***ios***

```
C:\Ionic-Chat-master>ionic platform add ios
```

and for ***android***

```
C:\Ionic-Chat-master>ionic platform add android
```

***3.Previewing*** on a mobile device(Be Sure your device is Connected)

for **ios**

```
C:\Ionic-Chat-master>ionic run ios -l –c
```

for **android**

```
C:\Ionic-Chat-master>ionic run android -l –c
```

***4.Deploy to an android*** device

```
C:\Ionic-Chat-master>ionic build android
```

These are the Commands which leads to achieve a ***.apk*** .

Comment: Perfect Answer.. That saves my day .

Comment: and then get apk from ~yourIonicProjectFolder\platforms\android\build\outputs\apk

Comment: Latest Ionic CLI run commands requires additional syntax, each command should be "ionic cordova" instead of "ionic". Works the same as above.

Comment: Keep in mind that once you have built an apk, you won't be able to just put it online somewhere and install it on your phone by visiting the link, you will then have to have `developer options` (Settings > About > tab `Build number` 5 times on phone) enabled to allow `unknown sources`, then you will also have to `sign the APK` and `zipalign it` - basically adding a identity and password to it, which is utilised for marketplace updates, this will then allow it to be installed on your phone. Instructions can be found here: http://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/guide/publishing.html

Answer (score 7):

First of all you have to install

1. node.js
2. apache ANT
3. Java JDK & JRE
4. Android SDk & Eclipse

and then after all installation you have to set this all software path into environmental- variable. and then fire your `npm install -g cordova`. without this all software installation and there path setup your phoneGap application will not created. and still you have any confusion and any question related software installation and there path setup then again tell me i will help you.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way, no need to install anything:

`ionic package build android`

*(magic happens in the cloud)*

Then you can download `.apk` to a computer or your Android device.

Comment: download from where

Comment: @abhayendra *(magic happens in the cloud)* - http://blog.ionic.io/build-apps-in-minutes-with-ionic-package/

Comment: download from ~yourIonicProjectFolder\platforms\android\build\outputs\apk

Answer (score 1):

First create an account at Ionic Io ,

then in your project directory hit this - >

```
ionic io init
```

then log in there and hit this

```
ionic package build android
```

no need to install anything...

Answer (score 0):

```
ionic platform add android
ionic build --release android
```

Comment: Please do not simply copy-paste your answers (http://stackoverflow.com/a/34593917/466738) but make them relevant to the question.

Comment: that was also one of my solution for the same issue @tim castelijns

Comment: @ER.SHASHITIWARI what are you talking about

Answer (score 0):

We need to execute below mentioned steps to generate .apk with gradle build system:

Through out the steps I have assume that I am creating 'MyApp' project

Step 1 : generate myapp.keystore file using below mentioned command :

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore myapp.keystore -alias myapp -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

Step 2 : create ant.properties file with following details :

```
storeFile=myapp.keystore
storePassword=<<your keystore password>>
keyAlias=myapp
keyPassword=<<your keystore password>>
```

Step 3 : create gradle.properties file with the path to set ant.properties file :

```
cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile= <<path to ant.properties>>
```

Step 4 : Use last command as mentioned below :

```
ionic build android --release
```

Note : You must have set path for : java, adb, jarsigner, zipalign

Your generated apk will be in build folder.

Answer (score 0):

for ionic 3 add `ionic login` enter email and pwd
then

```
ionic package build android
```

please login and check the apk file.