# How to build apk using ionic with angular

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have downloaded same app like "Ionic-Chat-master" and i want make this app to apk file..

I have tried the following link [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31835399/how-to-make-apk-file-using-ionic-framework-with-angular)

But its not working, when i got to that project directory and i tried following command "**ionic platform add android**" but its displying erro'**cordova' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file**. i have installed npm module in corresponding project directory.. 
Please help any one to resolve this...

Comment: is Cordova installed?

Comment: How to check whether its installed or not using command prompt?

Comment: type npm in command prompt

Comment: Check if you have cordova installed: `cordova -v`, if you don't get a version, install it: `npm install -g cordova`, looks like you forgot to install it with ionic.